# Convert majority of dataframe variables to factor

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `data1` with 70 variables. 67 of them need to be converted to a factor, it is except variables `var1, var2, var3`.  I know how to convert variable per variable:

```
data1$var4 <- as.factor(data1$var4)
```

However in order not to do it 67 times, I would like to know if there is a way to convert all the variables to factor by making the exception of only `var1, var2, var3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>%
    mutate(
        across(-c(var1, var2, var3), factor)
    )
```

Edit: with `repex` proving it works.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(purrr)
data1 <- tibble(
    var1 = runif(10),
    var2 = runif(10),
    var3 = runif(10),
    var4 = 1:10,
    var5 = 1:10
) %>% 
    mutate(
        across(-c(var1, var2, var3), factor)
    )
data1
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>      var1  var2  var3 var4  var5 
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>
#>  1 0.241  0.609 0.694 1     1    
#>  2 0.948  0.550 0.548 2     2    
#>  3 0.782  0.822 0.419 3     3    
#>  4 0.305  0.603 0.607 4     4    
#>  5 0.819  0.666 0.136 5     5    
#>  6 0.693  0.330 0.467 6     6    
#>  7 0.169  0.222 0.585 7     7    
#>  8 0.228  0.539 0.218 8     8    
#>  9 0.689  0.191 0.826 9     9    
#> 10 0.0137 0.745 0.798 10    10
data1 %>% 
    map(class)
#> $var1
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> $var2
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> $var3
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> $var4
#> [1] "factor"
#> 
#> $var5
#> [1] "factor"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: it has given no error, however I still see the variable type "int". What might be the reason?

Comment: Did you save your new object with the `<-`? Or is this from the output of the code? You could try replacing `factor` with `as.factor`. Did you check `class(data1$var4)`?

Comment: i have saved the new object with <- and have also tried to replace with as.factor. The result is the same. the class is as follows: [1] "integer" before converting  and after.

Comment: I can not reproduce what you are saying. So I am sorry if I do not belive you as you can clearly see from the repex in my upndated awnser that it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)    
data1 <- data1 %>%
      mutate_at(vars(c("var1", "var2", "var3")), factor)
```

Comment: it has given no error, however I still see the variable type "int". What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution is:

```r
# create a data frame as an example
dat <- data.frame(var1 = 1:3, var2 = 3:1, var3 = 5:7, 
                  var4 = letters[1:3], var5 = LETTERS[1:3])

# convert all but var1, var2, and var3 to factors
to_change <- !names(dat) %in% c("var1", "var2", "var3")
dat[to_change] <- lapply(dat[to_change], factor)

# show the new data set
str(dat)
#R> 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
#R>  $ var1: int  1 2 3
#R>  $ var2: int  3 2 1
#R>  $ var3: int  5 6 7
#R>  $ var4: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
#R>  $ var5: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
```

You can also use `to_change <- setdiff(names(dat), c("var1", "var2", "var3"))`.